Vite and .htaccess resulting in 404 not found
I'm building a React project with Vite. I want to be able to map, for instance:
https://example.com/project/edit/0123456789abcdef
to:
https://example.com/project/index.html?content=editor&id=0123456789abcdef
When I do this in .htaccess:
RewriteRule ^.*edit/([0-9a-f]+)$    index.html?content=editor&shid=$1 [L,QSA]

It will load index.html okay, but then I end up with:
GET https://example.com/project/edit/assets/index-CVjGBOj5.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://example.com/project/edit/assets/index-DYA3CczB.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

because of the Vite-generated code:
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index-DYA3CczB.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="./assets/index-CVjGBOj5.css">

Now I get, sort of, why this is happening. I get that the redirect is still using https://example.com/project/edit/ as the base URL when it resolves ./assets/..., but is there any way to...not do that?
Not everything will open index.html via the same route, so I can't assume we'll be redirecting from a nested path and accommodate it that way somehow. Sometimes I'll be opening index.html directly.
All I'm wondering is if it's possible to have /some/project/path redirect to some/index.html?arg1=project&arg2=path, and have the base URL resolve properly as well.

Use RewriteBase /project and an absolute rewriting target /index.html.

"I get that the redirect is still using ... as the base URL when it resolves ./assets/...," - has nothing to do with the redirect; the browser resolves relative URLs to absolute ones. "but is there any way to...not do that?" - you could use a base element to set the base URL to resolve all(!) relative URLs against; or (if possible) you could make vite generate URLs that start with a slash - those are relative to the domain root.
